# How to configure Eclipse PDT? (Make it more like Dreamweaver)

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, dreamweaver, eclipse-pdt

I am migrating from Adobe Dreamweaver to Eclipse's PDT. So far, I've enabled some of the intellisense features, but not the following:

1. In Dreamweaver, whenever the `$` symbol is typed, the software brings up a list of all the global functions and variables (`$_SERVER`, `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`, etc). I haven't been able to reproduce that in PDT.
2. In Dreamweaver, whenever the `new` keyword is typed, all the classes are displayed, along with their parameters. Even though some of the classes are displayed in PDT, the arguments for the classes are not included. So, if I decide to use a class, I have no idea what parameters to pass into the constructor.
3. In Dreamweaver, I don't have to create a project before starting a PHP application; just create a folder, and start; it seems I have to always start by creating a project in Eclipse.

So, 4 main questions:

1. Is there a way to solve the first problem?
2. Is there a way to solve the second problem? I would very much try to avoid opening up a PHP.net manual every time I need to code.
3. Is there a way to start a project without creating one? Do I have to build the project after it's complete before I can use it as an application? How do I modify existing PHP applications in Eclipse without creating a new project?
4. If all these are impossible, is there a free or low budget (<= $100) IDE with all these features that I can use?

Comment: Hitting ctrl+space should solve some of the autocomplete issues IIRC

Comment: Eclipse PDT definitely does #1. Are you perhaps not using the PHP perspective in Eclipse?

Comment: @Asaph, yes...I'm using PHP Perspective. Anytime I type '$', and then ctrl-space, it brings this message 'No completions available'